# FactoryPattern with derived generic classes

Tags: c#, generics, factory-pattern, derived-class, base-class

This is a short snipped that gets to the point, I hid details that irrelevant. The goal is to make my factory work with my generics designed types. At the end of the post I have my two observations.

**Interface**

```
public interface IWorker<T> where T : IWorkload 
{
    T CraftWorkload(string plainWorkload);
    Task DoWork(T workload);
}
```

**IWorkload**

```
public interface IWorkload
{
    // some properties
}
```

**Base class**

```
internal abstract class Worker<T> : IWorker<T> where T : IWorkload
{
    public T CraftWorkload(string workAsJsonString)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(workAsJsonString, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
        });
    }

    public abstract Task DoWork(T workload);
}
```

**Another derived base class**

```
internal abstract class RestWorker<T> : Worker<T> where T : IWorkload
{ 
  // this is a worker that interact with http requests
}
```

**Concrete workers**

```
internal class WorkerA: RestWorker<WorkerA_Workload>
{
    public override Task DoWork(WorkerA_Workload workload)
    {
    }
}

internal abstract class WorkerB: Worker<WorkerB_Workload>
{
    public override Task DoWork(WorkerB_Workload workload)
    {
    }
}
```

**WorkersFactory**

`MessageType` is an enum that identifies a worker with a type

```
internal interface IWorkerFactory
{
    IWorker<IWorkload> GetWorker(MessageType type);
}

internal class WorkerFactory : IWorkerFactory
{
    public IWorker<IWorkload> GetWorker(MessageType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case MessageType.WorkerA:
                return new WorkerA() as IWorker<IWorkload>;
            case MessageType.WorkerB:
                return new WorkerB() as IWorker<IWorkload>;
           .
           .
           .
           .
           .
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("The type must be a type that maps to an available worker");
        }
    }
}
```

Two observation:

1. If I change the Factory to return without the implicit casting to `IWorker<IWorkload>` it gets confused
2. If I cast (as shown in the code) it returns null

Is my inheritance makes sense?

Comment: The keyword in servy's answer is **variance**. Your interface is *invariant*. An `IWorker<ConcreteWorkLoad>` is not an `IWorker<IWorkLoad>`

Answer (score 2):

Your `IWorker<T>` interface represents a worker that is able to both produce objects of type `T`, *and* consume objects of type `T` (since it uses `T` as both a parameter to a method and a return type of a method).  That means an `IWorker<IWorkload>` is an object that is able to produce objects of type `IWorkload`, which `WorkerA` and `WorkerB` can do, as the `WorkerA_Workload` and `WorkerB_Workload` objects they produce are `IWorkload` objects.  But it also means that an `IWorker<IWorkload>` needs to be able to accept *any `IWorkload` and do work on it.  **Neither `WorkerA` nor `WorkerB` can do that.**  They can only accept `WorkerA_Workload` and `WorkerB_Workload` inputs respectively, but in order to implement the interface of `IWorker<IWorkload>` they would need to be able to accept *any other type of workload*.

If your workers can actually accept *any* `IWorkload`, and they don't actually need to accept a specific type of workload, then you need to adjust your code to basically remove all generic types constrained to IWorkload and instead just use a non-generic `IWorkload` type in all of those places.  (You'll also need to make `IWorker<T>` covariant with respect to `T`.)

If your workers *can't* actually accept any `IWorkload`, and need a specific type of workload, then you can't treat all of your workers as an `IWorker<IWorkload>`, you need to always treat them as an `IWorker<T>` where T is the actual specific workload type they can accept.